# Is there a way to modify the label prop from the gifted-chat component?

Tags: react-native, components

I am using Gifted Chat https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/ but I need some labels to be in another language, namely the LoadEarlier label found here: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/src/LoadEarlier.tsx

defined here:

```
  static defaultProps = {
    onLoadEarlier: () => {},
    isLoadingEarlier: false,
    label: 'Load earlier messages',
    containerStyle: {},
    wrapperStyle: {},
    textStyle: {},
    activityIndicatorStyle: {},
    activityIndicatorColor: 'white',
    activityIndicatorSize: 'small',
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onLoadEarlier: PropTypes.func,
    isLoadingEarlier: PropTypes.bool,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    containerStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    wrapperStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    textStyle: PropTypes.any,
    activityIndicatorStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    activityIndicatorColor: PropTypes.string,
    activityIndicatorSize: PropTypes.string,
  }
```

I am using the chat like intended by importing the `react-native-gifted-chat` component and then just using `<GiftedChat />` as part of the props it has:

```
loadEarlier={true}
          isLoadingEarlier={false}
```

I want to know if there's some way I can reach that label to modify the "Load earlier messages" to another language. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you should use the `renderLoadEarlier` prop to render a `<LoadEarlier>` button with a custom label.

import it-

```
import { LoadEarlier } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
```

then in render -

```
    render() {

        const myLoadEarlier = (props) => <LoadEarlier {...props} label="Custom Load Earlier Label" />;

        return(
            <View>
                ...
                <GiftedChat
                    ...
                    renderLoadEarlier={myLoadEarlier}
                />
            </View>
        );
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Excellent. Thanks! 